# Infinite while loop and control-c

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

So, I wrote the following code:

```
void main(void) {

int charNums[ALPHABET], i = 1;
char word[MAX];

while(i) {

    initialize(charNums, word);

    getString(word);
    setLetters(charNums, word);

    getString(word);
    checkLetters(charNums, word);

    if(isZero(charNums))
        printf("Anagram\n");
    else
        printf("Not anagram\n");
}
}
```

The while loop is infinite, which it is supposed to be.  My professor said something about using CTRL-C to exit the infinite while loop, but that doesn't work with what I've coded.  Am I missing something simple or what?  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Thank you!  (Note: this is only a portion of the code.)

Comment: You can test a condition with `if` and the use `break;` to break the loop

Comment: Can you make the condition hitting ctrl-c?  If so, then how does one go about coding something like that?

Comment: Made a answer with a signal handler so it checks if your hitting ctrl-c!

Comment: Appreciate all the help.  Apparently, according to the professor, he made a mistake and, ctrl-c to exit a program in Visual Studio, it does not work with the development environment we are using.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i'm adding a signal handler which checks if you press ctrl + c and if so it's stops the loop)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t stop;

void inthand(int signum) {
    stop = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    signal(SIGINT, inthand);

    while (!stop)
        printf("loop\n");

    printf("exiting safely\n");
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

So i think your program should look something like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t stop;

void inthand(int signum) {
    stop = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    signal(SIGINT, inthand);

    int charNums[ALPHABET], i = 1;
    char word[MAX];

    while(!stop) {

        initialize(charNums, word);

        getString(word);
        setLetters(charNums, word);

        getString(word);
        checkLetters(charNums, word);

        if(isZero(charNums))
            printf("Anagram\n");
        else
            printf("Not anagram\n");
    }

    printf("exiting safely\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: dont forget to initialize stop =0 before the while loop

Answer (score 1):

```
while(1)
{
}
```

This is a infinite loop there should be some condition in the while loop to break out of it.
`ctrl+c` will terminate you program. So instead of ctrl+c there should be some condition within the loop to `break` out of it.
If `ctrl+c` should be used to break out of the loop then you need to use a `signal handler` to handle your `ctrl+c` signal

Comment: We were specifically told to use ctrl-c

Comment: @user3727648 Then you need to use signal handler to handle `ctrl+C`