# Start executable as background process, redirecting stderr to file, and obtain PID, in single cmd.exe window via batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have seen:

- [How to start an application without waiting in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937569/how-to-start-an-application-without-waiting-in-a-batch-file)
- [How can I run a program from a batch file without leaving the console open after the program starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-leaving-the-console-open-after)
- [How to get PID of process just started from within a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486960/how-to-get-pid-of-process-just-started-from-within-a-batch-file/51319981)
- [Is there any way to redirect stderr output from a command run with "start" in the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309441/is-there-any-way-to-redirect-stderr-output-from-a-command-run-with-start-in-th)

... but I still cannot really get what I want working, so here goes my question.

I have a program that basically loops forever (until interrupted with Ctrl-C), and outputs log messages to `stderr`; here is an example, `testlogerr.c`:

```c
// based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965508/infinite-while-loop-and-control-c
// can be compiled in MINGW64 with:
// gcc -g testlogerr.c -o testlogerr.exe

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t stop;

void inthand(int signum) {
  stop = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  signal(SIGINT, inthand);
  int counter = 0;

  while(!stop) {
    fprintf( stderr, "%d: Logging line %d\n", (int)time(NULL), counter++);
    sleep(2);
  }

  printf("exiting safely\n");
  //system("pause"); // does "Press any key to continue . . ."; skip here
  return 0;
}
```

Now, having built this program (in MINGW64) as a Windows .exe, I would like to start it via a batch script in `cmd.exe` as a background process, having its stderr redirected to a log file, and obtaining its PID as a process. To do this, in Linux `bash` I'd simply do (see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74520/can-i-redirect-output-to-a-log-file-and-background-a-process-at-the-same-time , [How to get process ID of background process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-process-id-of-background-process)):

```sh
testlogerr > myfile.log 2>&1 &
TESTLOGERR_PID=$!
echo "testlogerr started, its PID is $TESTLOGERR_PID"
```

My question is: how can I do the same in a batch script, so I get only one `cmd.exe` window started, and I get a prompt in that window after the background process has started?

As far as I've seen from the links above, `start /b` would start a command in background - but then one cannot obtain the PID of the background process.

Furthermore, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971707/6197439 recommends PowerShell, so I tried the following, e.g. as `testlogerr.bat`:

```
powershell -executionPolicy bypass -command ^
 "& {$process = start-process $args[0] -passthru -argumentlist $args[1..($args.length-1)]; exit $process.id}" ^
 testlogerr.exe 2>testlogerr.log
```

... however, the problem is - when I double-click this `testlogerr.bat` file in Windows Explorer:

- First one `cmd.exe` terminal window gets started, then it closes, and the `testlogerr.exe` gets started in *another* `cmd.exe` window
- The `cmd.exe` terminal window where `testlogerr.exe` runs, shows no `cmd.exe` prompt - instead, it shows stderr log messages; meaning it is running in foreground, not background

  - Another indication of foreground run, is that when I hit Ctrl-C, `testlogerr.exe` exits - and so does its terminal `cmd.exe` window
- The `testlogerr.log` file gets created, but its empty

So - how can I start the program as a background process, redirecting its stderr to file, obtain and print its pid, and finally show a `cmd.exe` terminal prompt (while the started process runs in the background) - all in a single `cmd.exe` terminal window?

Comment: to debug your powershell code which you call from `cmd` just add pause as the last line to ensure you see why it failed. Alternatively you can open `cmd` `cd` to the script and run from there to see the output.

Comment: Thanks @Gerhard - but I don't think the powershell code failed per se: there are no error messages, and it does start the process - just not in the "background" (or redirection) sense that I expected ... So, I either need different switches for powershell (and I don't know it at all) - or I need a different approach altogether (which I also have no idea about, as I don't usually work in `cmd.exe`).

Comment: Thanks @Gerhard: "Does the exe send the PID to stdout" - I guess so, but that first terminal window closes too fast; "you can use tasklist to determine the PID" - yes, but I want to avoid "grepping" through tasklist, since there may be two or more processes of the same name. Still, I'd like to achieve this in one `cmd.exe` window only, without starting a second one.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux shell, `$!` stores the last executed `PID`. Powershell can achieve the same using `$process.id` The current `PowerShell` code only exists with the `PID` though and is never displayed. Therefore change the code in the batch file to use `Write-Host` to display the PID (Similar to `echo` in bash):

```
@echo off
powershell -executionPolicy bypass -command "& {$process = start-process $args[0] -passthru -argumentlist $args[1..($args.length-1)]; Write-Host testlogerr started, its PID is $process.id}" testlogerr.exe 2>testlogerr.log
pause>nul
```

PS!! If you want both `stdout` and `stderr` in the log file, then change from `2>testlogerr.log` to `>testlogerr.log 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks @Gerhard - not sure if you tried that batch code; but unfortunately, that approach pipes the messages from the .exe process directly in the terminal (and not in the log file), and I do not get a prompt in the same terminal, so I can work further. I managed finally to put together a working code, though - see my answer (it was not exactly trivial, as you'll see by my many failures).

Comment: Not possible for me to try the code and expect results as I do not have access to your executable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got this - after a *ton* of failed attempts ...

First, let me note that I expected a "line buffered" redirection; however, Windows has no support for that, it either has "character buffered" I/O (serial ports), or it buffers everything (until process exits, then its output is flushed to file). However, the buffering happens at the output of the program - so to make sure my program is unbuffered, I made these changes (if you do not have control over the program you want to run in that way, see one of the referred links where they suggest using `winpty` for "unbuffer"ing) in `testlogerr.c`:

```c
// based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965508/infinite-while-loop-and-control-c
// can be compiled in MINGW64 with:
// gcc -g testlogerr.c -o testlogerr.exe

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t stop;

void inthand(int signum) {
  stop = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  // disable output/line buffering:
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192318/why-does-delayed-expansion-fail-when-inside-a-piped-block-of-code#8194279
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487671/is-out-host-buffering
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516258/what-is-the-equivalent-of-unbuffer-program-on-windows
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876660/how-to-turn-off-buffering-of-stdout-in-c
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

  signal(SIGINT, inthand);
  int counter = 0;

  while(!stop) {
    fprintf( stderr, "%d: Logging line %d\n", (int)time(NULL), counter++);
    sleep(2);
  }

  printf("exiting safely\n");
  //system("pause"); // does "Press any key to continue . . ."; skip here
  return 0;
}
```

Right, so now that we have a program that writes "unbuffered" (i.e. "character buffered") to stderr, this is the batch file that works for me, `testlogerr.bat` - first the working portion, then for reference, everything else that did not work for me:

```bat
:: so, the only way to prevent Ctrl-C, AND run in the same cmd.exe window started by .bat, AND obtain the PID of the background process, is to use start /b - and then, retrieve the PID from the difference in started tasks ..
:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677462/windows-batch-file-pid-of-last-process
@echo off
tasklist /FI "imagename eq testlogerr.exe" /NH /FO csv > task-before.txt
start /b testlogerr.exe > testlogerr.log 2>&1
tasklist /FI "imagename eq testlogerr.exe" /NH /FO csv > task-after.txt

for /f "delims=, tokens=2,*" %%A in ('"fc /L /LB1  task-before.txt task-after.txt | find /I "testlogerr.exe""') do set TESTPID=%%A
del task-before.txt
del task-after.txt
:: next command deletes double quotes (") from the string itself, so only the PID number remains: 
SET TESTPID=%TESTPID:"=%
:: now, print the PID we obtained:
echo TESTPID is %TESTPID%
:: note that at this point, the started terminal actually blocks!
:: so here we run cmd.exe one more time, so we get the command prompt shell
cmd
:: to exit this cmd shell, first you have to do `taskkill /F /PID %TESTPID%`, and only then `exit` will work
:: (otherwise it blocks) - or, just close via the X button at upper right corner of the cmd.exe window


REM Failed approaches below:


REM :: there is -RedirectStandardError for powershell Start-Process;
REM :: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1
REM :: that means we do not have to start cmd so we have stream redirection; however,
REM :: -RedirectStandardError causes the reading via for..in..do to freeze (otherwise the below works)
REM @echo off
REM for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process testlogerr.exe -RedirectStandardError testlogerr.log -NoNewWindow -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id"') DO set i=%%i
REM echo i was %i%
REM pause


REM :: also "batch macro" https://stackoverflow.com/q/69539939/ does not work,
REM :: when RedirectStandardError is there (but works otherwise)
REM @echo off
REM call :initMacro
REM %$set% TESTPID="powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process testlogerr.exe 2>testlogerr.log -NoNewWindow -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id"" 
REM echo TESTPID %TESTPID[0]%
REM ...


REM :: piping to SET https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318 also does not work:
REM powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process testlogerr.exe -RedirectStandardError testlogerr.log -NoNewWindow -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id" | set /p TESTPID=
REM echo TESTPID %TESTPID%
REM pause


REM :: must redirect to files, then https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318 - this works:
REM :: openfiles /local on :: requires system reboot!
REM :: note: somehow test.pid here ends up being held/"used by" testlogerr.exe? yes, see https://superuser.com/q/986202 ; that means we cannot really delete it (ugh!)
REM @echo off
REM powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process testlogerr.exe -RedirectStandardError testlogerr.log -NoNewWindow -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id" > test.pid
REM set /p TESTPID=<test.pid
REM :: openfiles /query /fo table | findstr test.pid :: access denied
REM :: del test.pid
REM echo TESTPID %TESTPID%
REM pause


REM :: like this, though, test.pid is not kept under ownership, so we can easily delete it
REM @echo off
REM powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process testlogerr.exe -RedirectStandardError testlogerr.log -NoNewWindow -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -FilePath .\test.pid" 
REM set /p TESTPID=<test.pid
REM del test.pid
REM echo TESTPID %TESTPID%
REM :: pause :: not needed anymore, no need for "Press any key to continue . . ."
REM :: note that at this point, the started terminal actually blocks!
REM :: so here we run cmd.exe one more time, so we get the command prompt shell
REM :: (however, even there, if we hit Ctrl-C, it will break our background program!)
REM cmd


REM :: as per https://superuser.com/q/1479119
REM :: like this, Ctrl-C does not kill the process by accident anymore;
REM :: however, the PID returned is for the cmd.exe, not the testlogerr.exe
REM @echo off
REM powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process -FilePath 'CMD.EXE' -ArgumentList '/C START /B testlogerr.exe' -RedirectStandardError testlogerr.log -NoNewWindow -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -FilePath .\test.pid" 
REM set /p TESTPID=<test.pid
REM del test.pid
REM echo TESTPID %TESTPID%
REM cmd


REM :: so, the only way to prevent Ctrl-C, AND run in the same cmd.exe window started by .bat, AND obtain the PID of the background process, is to use start /b - and then, retrieve the PID from the difference in started tasks ..
REM :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677462/windows-batch-file-pid-of-last-process
REM ( ... here was the working code, which has now been moved at start/top of snippet)
```

So, what this `.bat` file now allows me, is that I can double click it, and I will get in the newly started `cmd.exe` terminal window:

```
TESTPID is 5532
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1266]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\tmp>
```

So, the `testlogerr.exe` process started in the background - but if I hit Ctrl-C by accident in the newly started `cmd.exe` terminal, I will not shut `testlogerr.exe` down.

Furthermore, `testlogerr.exe`'s log messages are piped to the `testlogerr.log` file (and I can confirm lines in that logfile appear one by one - if we had Linux `tail`, we could have seen realtime updates with `tail -f testlogerr.log`).

And finally, I get a `cmd.exe` shell prompt at end - which means, I can immediately inspect the situation:

```
C:\tmp>tasklist | findstr 5532
testlogerr.exe                5532 Console                    1      3,148 K
```

Great, that works!

Unfortunately, I thought this would allow me to start *two* such terminals, with two separate instances of the background process - unfortunately, if I try to do that, I get in the second terminal:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
TESTPID is "=
```

But, at least I got the behavior that I wanted in the OP/question ...